# Как сделать ссылку вида index.php?do=register

Tags: php, ссылки

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как делают ссылки вида:

```
http://sait.com/index.php?do=register
```

Т.е. На главной пользователь нажал на регистрацию, и его перекинуло по данной ссылки. Как такое можно сделать?

**UPD.** Я делаю регистрацию как отдельный пхп файл (`register.php`), при переходе в котором и происходит регистрация. Интересует, как сделать, чтобы в именно в файле `index.php`, по выше указанной ссылке начиналась регистрация.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте параметр `'do'` в массиве `$_GET` на соответствие строке `'register'`.  
Т.е.:

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'register')
{
    // ваша магия
}
```

Только для того, чтобы результат выглядел культурно и был легко поддерживаемым, надо хорошенько это продумать. Почитайте как работаю с маршрутизацией в каких-либо фреймворках.

Answer (score 0):

Какой вопрос, такой ответ:

```
<a href="http://sait.com/index.php?do=register">регистрация</a>
```

Согласно правилам форума, укажите, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Ну на HTML и я могу такое сделать:) Обновил в UPD свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset($_GET['do'] ) && $_GET['do'] == 'register' )
{
    header( 'Location: /register.php' ); exit();
}
```