# Как сделать установщик на PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Как делается так, чтобы в пределах одного PHP-файла, например, `anketa.php`, можно было идти на следующий пункт в том же файле (нажатием кнопки «Далее» вывести следующий пункт, к примеру).

Пусть будет такая ситуация.

1. Пользователя идет на страницу анкеты (`anketa.php`).
2. Там одно поле ввода и внизу кнопка ДАЛЕЕ.
3. Он вводит имя «Чувак» и нажимает кнопку ДАЛЕЕ.
4. Появляется новое поле ввода, там написано: "Что ты куришь, брат?"
5. Он вписывает слово Банзай и жмет ДАЛЕЕ.
6. Появляется 2 слова:

   > Имя: Чувак
   >   Курит: Банзай
   >   Отныне ты записан в БД

Я хочу научиться делать такое в пределах одного файла.

Я могу ужасным методом. В файле `anketa.php` первое поле, жмем ДАЛЕЕ (переменная уходит в сессию) его перебрасывает в файл `anketa2.php`, там он вводит что курит, жмет ДАЛЕЕ (эта тоже в сессию, итого в 2 переменные) и в файле anketa_result.php выводится то, что он вписал, и сходу пишется в БД.

А вот, как всё это в одном файле, я не знаю (типа `anketa.php?question=2`).

Пожалуйста, подскажите мне простенький код, чтобы я уже дальше в нем разбирался, или ссылку может на статью какую-нибудь.

Comment: Уже был [похожий вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/80082/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) о пошаговой регистрации

Comment: У вас немножко страдают фундаментальные знания в предметной области. Не знаю, с чего лучше вам посоветовать начать, но, что касается данного вопроса, посоветовал бы почитать о конечных автоматах (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82), о cостояниях, о протоколе без состояний, которым является HTTP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).

Comment: PHP - серверный код, а то что вы объясняете - это клиентская часть. Вы можете использовать плагин наподобие https://github.com/wbotelhos/stepy для создания формы и в самом конце отсылать данные на сервер посредством стандартного SUBMIT, отображая введённые данные посредством JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Пара вариантов:

1) сделать это динамически в рамках одной страницы, без перезагрузки, на JS (jQuery);

2) в зависимости от пришедших параметров показывать разные формы из `anketa.php`: нет параметров: первое пустое поле; есть Имя — показать Имя и пустое ЧтоКуришь; есть и то и то — третий вариант. Если Имя есть - показывать форму, где это поле содержит введённое значение и у этого поля стоит атрибут `readonly="readonly"`. Значения формы передавать POSTом:

```
$name  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$brand = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'brand', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if( empty($name) && empty($brand)) {
    // показываем форму с пустым полем для имени
} elseif( !empty($name) && empty($brand)) {
    // показываем форму с заполненным именем readonly или вообще hidden и пустым полем для brand
} elseif( !empty($name) && !empty($brand)) {
    // Вас зовут Вася и вы курите Беломор
} else {
    // фигня какая-то, этого не может быть : )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Несерьёзно всё это - [всего 4 дня назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136121/%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-index-php-do-register).

```
$question = isset($_GET['question']) ? $_GET['question'] : 1;

if ($question == 1)
{
     // магия первого вопроса
}
// еще магии?
```

А уж как это будет запрашиваться (с перезагрузкой или ajax'ом) скрипту *почти* параллельно.

Сессии же остаются сессиями - в них и храните.

Повторюсь. Для того, чтобы результат выглядел культурно и был легко поддерживаемым, надо хорошенько это продумать. Почитайте как работаю с маршрутизацией в каких-либо фреймворках.

Comment: Ссылка на "4 дня назад" 404

Comment: @sergiks, спасибо. Ссылку обновил

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
session_start();
$steps = array('name','smoke');
$_SESSION['user'] = array('name'=>'','smoke'=>'');
$_SESSION['step'] = 0;
$step = $steps[$_SESSION['step']];
if(!empty($_POST[$step])){
   $_SESSION['user'][$step] = $_POST[$step];
   $_SESSION['step']++;
   if($_SESSION['step']>=count($steps)){
    print('Отныне ты записан в БД');
   }
}

$questions = array('Как тебф зовут?','Что ты куришь?');

?>
<form action='anketa.php' method='post'>
<label><?php print $questions[$step];?><input type='text' name='<?php print $step?>'></label>
<input type='submit' value='ok' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

По кнопке далее отправляешь формы на этот же файл, но с разным параметром, например step
Внутри пхп берешь этот параметр из $_POST или $_GET и выводишь соответствующую страницу.